# Creating a 1/2 Circle motion effect

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

(Excuse the poor attempt of a drawing)

The "pie" and "slices" are made with just css, what I'd like to do is have them "swipe in" from left to right in a particular order, starting with the circle (div.circle), for say 3 seconds, then once that completes, the red, and then the green.

Hopefully someone can understand what I'm attempting to say...

```
<div class="graph">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="pie-green"></div>
    <div class="pie-red"></div>
</div>


div.graph div.circle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 34%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-top-left-radius: 150px;
    border-top-right-radius: 150px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 15px 30px -20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 20px 15px 30px -20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 20px 15px 30px -20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
div.graph div.pie-green {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 24%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(14deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(14deg); 
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 140px solid transparent;
    border-right: 140px solid transparent;
    border-top: 200px solid #65A059;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.96;
    filter: alpha(opacity=96);
    z-index: 100;
}
div.graph div.pie-red {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(70deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(70deg);  
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 76px solid transparent;
    border-right: 76px solid transparent;
    border-top: 155px solid #C1100E;
    -moz-border-radius: 42%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 42%;
    border-radius: 42%;
}
```

Comment: Is it an SVG Image?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm trying to make this "swipe effect" happen only once the div.graph is visible on the page, since it is towards the end of the page, and not seen until the user scrolls down.

Comment: Sorry, that neither answers my question, nor it is clear.

Comment: No it is not, it is divs and css only.

Comment: It could be slightly tougher then. Have you tried `D3.js` or something?

Comment: Haven't tried anything, I don't even know where to begin. (Sorry, novice here)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131632/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-brad-guy).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using SVG. With CSS is virtually impossible to accomplish what you want.

I tried using [keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) to change the `transform: rotation()` value, but it's not enough. The pie rotates around it's own axis, so it's also necessary to change the `left` and `top` properties.

Even like that the result is not satisfactory. Check out [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4cqc413/) (click to begin animation).

Comment: I see what you mean. Do you know any good tutorials where to begin with SVG?